# How can I disable tab if it is active and enable it if I click other tab in Angular?

Tags: c#, html, angular, typescript

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/books" routerLinkActive="active 
 (click)="bookTabIsClicked()" >
      Books
</a>
```

I am currently learning Angular by myself.
I have this HTML, how can I disable this tab if this is active and if I click other tab, it will set to enable.

Answer (score 1):

For Example, if you have three tabs:

```html
<div class="tab-group">
  
  <button
    routerLink="/books"
    class="tab"
    routerLinkActive
    #rlaBooks="routerLinkActive"
    [disabled]="rlaBooks.isActive">
    Books
  </button>

  <button
    routerLink="/cars"
    class="tab"
    routerLinkActive
    #rlaCars="routerLinkActive"
    [disabled]="rlaCars.isActive">
    Cars
  </button>

  <button
    routerLink="/chickens"
    class="tab"
    routerLinkActive
    #rlaChickens="routerLinkActive"
    [disabled]="rlaChickens.isActive">
    Chickens
  </button>

</div>
```

Full example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-question-63095652

Code explanation:

```
#rlaBooks="routerLinkActive"
```

Exports the instance of the `routerLinkActive` directive. `#rlaBooks` declares the variable name to access the instance.

---

```
[disabled]="rlaBooks.isActive"
```

Sets the disabled attribute to true if the current router URL is equal to the specified URL in the `routerLink` directive. Else the disabled attribute is set to false.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: Please add an explanation to your code, so the user can understand your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

There are few different ways to do this, the easiest way I can think on is to add a variable directly in the view

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/books" routerLinkActive="active 
 (click)="bookTabIsClicked(); activeTab = 'bookTab'" [disabled]="activeTab == 'bookTab'">
      Books
</a>
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/books" routerLinkActive="active 
 (click)="bookTabIsClicked(); activeTab = 'otherTab'" [disabled]="activeTab == 'otherTab'">
      Other Tab
</a>
```

Initially since `activeTab` is undefined, all tabs will be enabled, once you click in one tab, `activeTab` will be assigned to the corresponding value turning the tab disabled immediattly